# how to solve this General error: 1364 Field doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel

I have a form to register tasks, the migrate file is as follows:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('Caption',300)->nullable();

            $table->string('TaskDsc',300)->nullable();
            
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('office_id');
            $table->foreign('office_id')->references('id')->on('offices');
            
            $table->date('TaskDate');
            $table->boolean('Type')->comment('0 for command and 1 for session') ;
            
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('Priority_id');
            $table->foreign('Priority_id')->references('id')->on('priorities');

            $table->string('TaskFile',100)->nullable();
            $table->date('StartDate');
            $table->date('EndDate');
            $table->smallInteger('Deadline')->comment('to day');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('Commander_id');
            $table->foreign('Commander_id')->references('id')->on('commanders');

            $table->json('OtherOffices')->nullable();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('Secretary_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('Secretary_id')->references('id')->on('offices');

            $table->smallInteger('SessionRowNo')->nullable();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('Status_id');
            $table->foreign('Status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and model file this code:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'caption',
        'taskDsc',
        'TaskDate',
        'type',
        'priority_id',
        'taskfile',
        'startDate',
        'endDate',
        'deadline',
        'office_id',
        'commander_id',
        'otheroffices',
        'Status_id'
    ];
```

and service file:

```
class TaskService 
{
    public function create($data)
    {
        return task::create($data);
    }

    public function update($task, $data)
    {
        return $task->update($data);
    }
}
```

and controller:

```
public function store(taskRequestStore $request,TaskService $service)
    {
        
        //   dd($request);
        $attributes = $request->all(['Caption','TaskDsc',
                                    'office_id','TaskDate','Priority_id',
                                    'Type','Taskfile','StartDate','EndDate','Deadline',
                                    'Commander_id','OtherOffices','Status_id'
                                    ]);
                    
        $office = $service->create($attributes)->tosql();
    }
```

when fill blade form and send form to store ,i recive this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'Type' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `tasks` (`office_id`, `TaskDate`, `Status_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 2024-02-27, 1, 2024-02-27 12:31:22, 2024-02-27 12:31:22))
```

By activating the dd command in controller, the value of the request is as follows:

```
+request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#1317 ▼
    #parameters: array:13 [▼
      "_token" => "JhLFgL6yLxNbH0ye6A9QQoSf3xIN9BpCBEsCSl5J"
      "Caption" => "this is caption"
      "TaskDate" => "۱۴۰۲-۱۲-۰۸"
      "type" => "1"
      "Priority_id" => "1"
      "taskDsc" => "<p><span style="background-color:rgb(255,255,255);color:rgb(33,37,41);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididun ▶"
      "formFile" => null
      "startDate" => null
      "deadline" => null
      "office_id" => "1"
      "otherOffices" => array:1 [▶]
      "commander_id" => "1"
      "Status_id" => "1"
    ]
  }
```

It seems that type has a value and there is no problem, but this error is issued. Of course, by giving the initial value to type, the error will be displayed for the priority_id field this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using a mix of snake case, camel case and anything in between.

Your $fillable does not match your database or what you are trying to retrieve and insert.
So you are trying to insert it into "Type", however, your $fillable is "type" (Notice the capital letter difference).

My recommendation is to keep every data variable as snake case "type", "start_date", "commander_id", etc.

Hope this was helpful.